# Prevent iframe redirect

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe

I'm having trouble adding a page from another website into my iframe. The link that automatically loads into my iframe, has what I think is called a top-redirect? It automatically redirects the user to their site, rather than just loading in my iframe. I've tried the following:

Added this to the  tag:

```
sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts"
```

That does absolutely nothing.

And I have tried this javascript code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return false; // This will stop the redirecting.
}
```

This javascript code works, but my browser asks me if I want to redirect or stop the script. I need it to not ask, but just choose to not run the script.

Now if I use the javascript code above, with sanbox="", it doesn't ask to stop the script upon loading, but it does upon leaving. How can I stop this popup?

Comment: have you tried setting sandbox="" ?

Comment: Are you accesing a page in the same domain? I know some pages do that as a security meassure to avoid people from crawling/scrapping data from their websites.

Comment: Preventing a page from unloading is useful in web forms and such, but it can easily be exploited by a malicious site to fool the user into staying on a page. That's why web browsers implement the standard message and have this mechanism for inserting custom text.

**See this answer :** stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own#276739

Comment: +1 it works!!!!! www.vdab.be was doing auto redirect but with this window.onbeforeunload works.